# Android portrait keyboard pop up changing my orientation to landscape

Tags: android-softkeyboard, landscape, portrait

So i have a bug on andriod devices where the keyboard pops up during portrait mode and the background changes (taking the landscape media queries)

I am currently testing on 360x640 devices (HTC One, Samsung S4 etc)

I read here and other webistes to use (max-aspect-ratio: 13/9) for portrait and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9) for landscape. However it is not working. This is my media queries for the portrait.

@media only screen

and (min-device-width:360px)

and (max-device-width:640px)

and (max-aspect-ratio: 13/9)

Someone please help me :)

Comment: Anyone? even willing to help :(

Comment: Please someone give me a hand? or tips?

Comment: Hi! Have you found any fix for this bug? I also have this issue. I haven't tested it on HTC devices, but it does happen on several Samsung devices. I tested it with Nexus and Motorola devices, but no issue with keyboard.

Comment: I use this tutorial and it helped me out~

http://blog.abouthalf.com/development/orientation-media-query-challenges-in-android-browsers/

Comment: I have this same problem.  looking for a solution on a galaxy s8

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9) {
```

instead of

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
```

seems to help. You just gott figure out a good aspect ratio that will cover most devices.

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20160509220835/http://blog.abouthalf.com/development/orientation-media-query-challenges-in-android-browsers/